# Silverlight activity control - messing up width and height?

Tags: silverlight, android-activity

I'm struggling with Silverlights' activity control. I placed a grid inside the activity control and no matter whether it shows "Loading..." or not, the grid doesn't stretch anymore, only the min-values are applied.
After removing the activity-control everything works fine, againg - but I need to use the ctrl.
Did I do something wrong?
Best regards,
rwh

```
Code:
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource DetailPageLayoutRoot}">
    <activity:Activity IsActive="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="200" Background="Bisque" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="50" Width="0.2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="50" Width="0.8*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="1" Background="Beige">
            ...
            </StackPanel>
            <controls:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" Width="4" MinWidth="4" MaxWidth="4"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="1" Background="AliceBlue">
                ...
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </activity:Activity>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Update:**

This control has now(Nov 2009) been incorporated into the Silverlight toolkit. Its been renamed the BusyIndicator. Get it [here](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight).

Original Answer:

*The latest version of the control fixes this problem.
Download it here: http://www.davidpoll.com/2009/09/14/update-2-displaying-background-activity-in-a-silverlight-ria-application/*

Comment: Dear Geoff, I just found the time to test your control, it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

P.S.: Just one hint to others using this control: For a now unknown reason I already had an ActivityControl.dll in my libs (from September), make sure to delete this first and check the file date after creating a reference, so that you use the new one.

Comment: @rwh- I've updated the answer. The control has now been included in the Silverlight toolkit so its probably best to get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I think it might be something wrong with the control.
You could set the minwidth/height programmatically. 
So innerGrid.minWidth = innerGrid.Parent.Parent.actualwidth;
Not sure if that will work though.

Comment: Thanks, for me it doesn't work, but I worked around it by setting the minwidth and minheight properties - at the cost of losing the very nicely working screen resizing of SL.